# Why doesn't strace catch all file accesses?

Tags: linux, unix

I'm trying to use strace to monitor all file accesses by g++ but it only seems to catch read accesses. Why isn't the file access for the output file shown?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

g++ calls other programs to do part of the build. If you want strace to trace those child processes, you need to use 'strace -f'.

Answer (score 0):

`g++` is just the frontend. It pipes the output to `as` directly.

Comment: Use `-f` to trace child processes as well.